# Return query by group

Tags: sql

Say I have the following tables:

Table 1

```
Name     Food 
______________
Sam      Chips
Tom      Chips
Larry    Chips
```

Table 2

```
Name     Type
_____________
Sam      Dip
Tom      Dip
Larry    Dip
Marry    Soda
Peter    Soda
Sam      Soda
Larry    Soda
Sam      Beer
Larry    Beer
```

Is is possible to return

```
Name    Type
____________
Sam     Dip
Tom     Dip
Larry   Dip
```

Using the names table 1 as a group and having that group exactly be match in table 2?

Soda Type won't match because it has Marry, Peter, Sam, Larry.
Beer Type only has Sam and Larry.

Comment: that's seems more like an inner join solution

Comment: Don't you mean 'lurker', not 'troll'?  And in the future, please include your RDBMS, although for this query a generic version should be possible.

Comment: Thanks luchosrock and clockwork-muse, inner join didnt do what i want. AdnreKR did what I needed, at least i know it can be done, just need to work on it more

Answer (score 1):

You could use subquery which will go like this if I understood your question correctly.

```
 select * 
 from table2 
 where name in (select name 
                from table 1 
                group by name);
```

Comment: I didn't notice, but there is multiple Larry's and Sam's because they have different types, So I think a group by is the only way.

Comment: @Nick I did not understand what your implying too.

Comment: Grouping will bring other types that i dont need, but thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
SELECT t1.Name, MIN(t2.Type)
FROM [Table 1] t1 JOIN [Table 2] t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

Comment: He's looking for matching groups, so this (by itself) isn't going to do what he needs - basically, he needs to find out the fact that the `Dip` group exactly matches the `Chips` group.

Comment: Oh I see. That table design seems very bad to me, but good job on noticing that and writing the query anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Use a full outer join and then check that nothing else is brought in.  The following query gets the "type"s that match:

```
select t2.type
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.name = t2.name
group by t2.type
having count(*) = count(t1.name) and -- all t1.names match
       count(*) = count(t2.name)     -- all t2.names match
       count(*) = (select count(*) from table1) -- all are present
```

This assumes no duplicate names.  Judicious use of `distinct` can fix that problem if necessary.

Once you have the type, you can join back to table2 to get all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can find these by asking for *the Types where the total number of entries in Table2 is the same as the number of common names and where there are no additional entries (names) in Table1*.

In SQL:

```
SELECT Table2.Name, Table2.Type
FROM
(
  SELECT Type
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM Table2) AS types
  WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table2 i2
    JOIN Table1 i1 ON i1.Name = i2.Name
    WHERE i2.Type = types.Type
  ) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table2 i2
    WHERE i2.Type = types.Type
  )
  AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table1
  ) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table2 i2
    WHERE i2.Type = types.Type
  )
) AS result
JOIN Table2 ON result.Type = Table2.Type
```

See it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d50e/1

In MySQL you can make use of the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to make a query that is shorter and easier to read:

```
SELECT Table2.Name, Table2.Type
FROM
(
  SELECT Type
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM Table2) AS types
  WHERE (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY Name)
    FROM Table2 i2
    WHERE i2.Type = types.Type
  ) = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY Name)
    FROM Table1
  )
) AS result
JOIN Table2 ON result.Type = Table2.Type
```

Be aware of [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html).

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af700/1

It wasn't absolutely clear that you really want to match the whole of Table1, but above solution can easily be extended for every matching combination of Food and Type:

```
SELECT result.Food, Table2.Name, result.Type
FROM
(
  SELECT Type, Food
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Type, Food FROM Table2 JOIN Table1) AS combinations
  WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table2 i2
    JOIN Table1 i1 ON i1.Name = i2.Name
    WHERE i2.Type = combinations.Type
    AND i1.Food = combinations.Food
  ) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table2 i2
    WHERE i2.Type = combinations.Type
  )
  AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table2 i2
    WHERE i2.Type = combinations.Type
  ) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table1 i1
    WHERE i1.Food = combinations.Food
  )
) AS result
JOIN Table2 ON result.Type = Table2.Type
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4d4b/1

Comment: Thanks AndreKR, doing this is Access with the SQL option. The first example got it right on, i'll need to do some tweeking to get it to work in Access. Thanks for the reply, at least i know it can be dont in sql.